# OSB Proxy Service using MQ Transport abruptly stops polling MQ

Tags: oracle, mq, osb

I've a proxy service of Messaging Service Type which polls messages from a MQ. Now this service is abruptly getting stuck sometimes. There will be no error logs or warning logs in the log files. If we change the Polling Interval of this service then It'll again start to run.

Did anybody face any similar kind of issues. Please advice how to fix this bug.

Comment: What version of OSB, MQ Client and MQ Server are you using?
Are there errors in the MQ logs?

A possible work-around would be using JMS Transport; though this transport has many down sides, it is quite reliable.

Comment: Which MQ?  WebSphere MQ? Active MQ? Sonic MQ?  Without more details, the question is unanswerable.